# Trying to restore files from DLT tape, have a/synchronous issues

Tags: c#, synchronization, backup

Currently using the code from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15487/Magnetic-Tape-Data-Storage-Part-Tape-Drive-IO-Co

Let's consider the following code:

```
public void Load(string tapeName)
    {
        // Try to open the file.
        m_handleValue = CreateFile(
            tapeName,
            GENERIC_READ,
            0,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE | FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
            IntPtr.Zero
            );

        if (m_handleValue.IsInvalid)
        {
            DisplayError();

            throw new TapeOperatorWin32Exception(
                "CreateFile", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }

        m_stream = new FileStream(
            m_handleValue,
            FileAccess.Read,
            32768,//65536,
            false
            );
    }

private void TestRead()
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
        m_stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        m_stream.Flush();
    }
```

And let's call it:

```
mTapeOperator.Load("\\\\.\\TAPE0");
mTapeOperator.TestRead();
```

I always got the following exception:

> Handle does not support synchronous operations. The parameters to the FileStream constructor may need to be changed to indicate that the handle was opened asynchronously (that is, it was opened explicitly for overlapped I/O).

The thing is, the handle was created with the synchronous flags, and the FileStream was created with isAsync = false.

The exact same code works fine when reading in a random file on my C:.

If I use BeginRead (asynchronous) instead of Read (synchronous), I have no exception until the EndRead is called. Then the same exception is raised.

Comment: 1/ The exception tells you to use async, do so. 2/ Does your drives supports async ? Check with another software to be sure. 3/ Have you considered asking the author at CodeProject ?

Comment: Thanks for reply! 1/ Since the author of the TapeOperator class made it synchronous, I was thinking it was for a reason, but maybe not. I'm trying right now, but got a strange error on BeginRead, which leads to the point number 2... 2/ How can I know if the drive I use supports asynchronous accesses? I'm reading from a Quantum DLT4000 SCSI Sequantial device. Can't find that explicitely in specifications :/ 3/ Unfortunately the author is retired and I can't find his contact :/

Comment: On page 79 it is explicitly said : http://downloads.quantum.com/dlt4000/dlt4000productmanual.pdf, some free software : http://www.uranium-backup.com/uranium-backup-free-download/ http://www.z-datdump.com/software.html (this one has command line), OTOH you could rewrite the thing from scratch there isn't ton of code.

Comment: Thanks for contribution @Aybe! For info, one must call the GetTapeParameters method with MEDIA parameter to prepare the tape to be accessed... If not, "Parameter is incorrect" exception is raised on BeginRead.